# Django, can't create app in subfolder

Tags: django, windows, path

I'm on windows and trying to create a new app inside a common folder named *Apps*.
The *myApp* folder already exists inside *Apps*. I'm running from the project root:

```
python manage.py startapp myApp Apps\myApp
```

and I get:

```
Error: 'Apps\\myApp' is not a valid app name. Please use only numbers, letters and underscores.
```

I don't know why that double backslash.
I tried also with a forward slash just to be sure:

```
python manage.py startapp myApp Apps/myApp
```

and I get this:

```
Error: 'myApp' conflicts with the name of an existing Python module and cannot be used as an app name. Please try another name.
```

I can't understand if it is a Windows or a Python problem.

Comment: does myApp actually conflict with an existing python module? what happens if you try "myApp2"?

Comment: actually, just spun up a windows vm, i think that's a real bug...

Comment: I've tried several names, I always get the same result. I actually copied an old app folder inside the _Apps_ folder, I added a `Apps\__init__.py`, synced the db and it seems to work. But still, I guess this is a workaround not a solution..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same trouble on my Mac as well. 
 I did solve it upgrading Django from vervion 1.3 to version 1.4.

Answer (score 39):

Try this:

```
mkdir Apps\newapp
python manage.py startapp NewApp Apps/newapp
```

And you will to create a app called "NewApp" inside folder "Apps/newapp".

Comment: Nope, it creates the NewApp folder inside the root and I get the error back: `Error: 'Apps\\newapp' is not a valid app name. Please use only numbers, letters and underscores.`. I guess it concerns that double backslash...

Comment: I'm on Xp, Django 1.4, no idea what's going on.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This solved my issue.  Let me put my two cents in it :) . Django 1.9,8 and above requires the app directory to be created first else it will throw an error directory does not exist.

Answer (score 18):

Create your **Apps** directory from your project's root directory-

```
mkdir Apps
```

Move to your **Apps** directory-

```
cd Apps
```

Run python by calling the manage.py in your root project directory-

```
python ../manage.py startapp newapp
```

There you go

Comment: Can you add some explanation? A plain code block alone isn't all that informative

Answer (score 10):

[from the docs:](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#startapp)

> If the optional destination is provided, Django will use that existing directory rather than creating a new one. You can use '.' to denote the current working directory.
>   `django-admin.py startapp myapp /Users/jezdez/Code/myapp`

So try `python manage.py startapp myApp ./Apps/myApp` or with the full path.

Comment: The dot '.' doesn't work on Windows, so I tried the absolute path `python manage.py startapp myApp D:\Documents\HOME\MyProject\Apps\myApp` and an app called *myApp* is created in the root folder and I get this error: `Error: 'D:\\Documents\\HOME\\MyProject\\Apps\\myApp' is not a valid app name. Please use only numbers, letters and underscores.` so as you can see all the backslashes are doubled, I think a Windows problem..

Comment: did you mess around with the PYTHONPATH variable?

Answer (score 3):

Manage.py file is a thin wrapper of django-admin.py

In case, you want to create a new app in any directory

Try this:

```
$ cd <directory path>
$ django-admin.py startapp <app-anme>
```

Comment: Did you test your code?
```
cd ./apps```
```python manage.py startapp myapp
```

python: can't open file 'manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: I found a working command that should be run after `cd <directory path>`:


`python /full/path/to/manage.py startapp myapp`

Answer (score 3):

For django 3.2.9

Create a sub directory `Apps` to hold all the apps, move into it, create a directory for the app `myApp`, then come back to root directory

```
mkdir Apps && cd Apps && mkdir myApp && cd ..
```

add a `__init__.py` file (is a python way to treat a directory as a package)

Create a myApp inside Apps sub directory

```
manage.py startapp myApp Apps/myApp
```

(in windows, please use backslash)
above two lines of code will create myApp

Now, in settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    # Local
    'Apps.myApp.apps.MyAppConfig', # new
]
```

in ./Apps/myApp/apps.py file, change `name='myApp'` to `name='Apps.myApp'` will solve the issue

Comment: This is what I was searching for. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

## For newer versions of Django

#### 1. Create the required folder structure

```bash
mkdir -p apps/myapp && touch apps/__init__.py
```

#### 2. Create the app

```bash
python manage.py startapp myapp apps/myapp
```

#### 3. Configure the `apps/myapp/apps.py` file as follows:

```py
from django.apps import AppConfig


class MyappConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
    name = 'apps.myapp'
```

#### 4. Append the app in the `INSTALLED_APPS` list at `[project]/settings.py`

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'apps.myapp',
]
```

### Tested on Django 4.2.3

Answer (score 1):

As the documentation says you can use the command

```
django-admin startapp name [directory]
```

but in the example

```
django-admin startapp myapp /Users/jezdez/myapp
```

the documentation does not say that python creates the myapp folder. You should do it before the startapp command.